# Python. Надо взять индексы повторяющихся элементов из списка и подставить в матрицу

Tags: python, list, матрицы

Задача отсюда https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/701/A

**Сообразил, что смог, но уткнулся в то, что когда ищу в изначальном списке число, то индекс берется только первый. Если возможно, то желательно решение без словарей или дефов, пока что не изучал.**

Условие:

В колоде карт есть n карт (n — чётное число). На каждой карте написано целое положительное число. В новую карточную игру будут играть n / 2 человек. Каждому из игроков перед началом игры будет роздано ровно по две карты, причём каждая карта из колоды будет роздана ровно одному игроку.

Перед вами стоит задача найти такой способ раздачи карт, чтобы у каждого из игроков сумма чисел, написанных на полученных им картах, совпадала. Гарантируется, что входные данные таковы, что это всегда возможно.

Входные данные
В первой строке входных данных записано целое положительное число n (2 ≤ n ≤ 100) — количество карт. Гарантируется, что n чётно.

Во второй строке следует последовательность из n целых положительных чисел a1, a2, ..., an (1 ≤ ai ≤ 100), где ai равно числу, написанному на i-й карте.

Выходные данные
Выведите n / 2 пар целых чисел, по одной паре в строке — номера карт, которые нужно отдать каждому игроку. Каждая карта должна быть роздана ровно одному игроку. Карты нумеруются в том же порядке, в котором описываются во входных данных, начиная с единицы. Гарантируется, что входные данные таковы, что ответ всегда существует. Если возможных правильных ответов несколько, разрешается вывести любой из них.

[image: пример]

```
n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = a.copy()
tmp = sum(a) // (n // 2)
a.sort()
a.reverse()
x = []

for i in range(n // 2):
    y = []
    j = 0
    while sum(y) != tmp:
        if (sum(y) + a[j]) <= tmp:
            y.append(a[j])
            del (a[j])
        else:
            j += 1
    x.append(y)

itog = []

for i in range(n // 2):
    itog.append([0] * 2)

for i in range(n//2):
    for j in range(2): 
        itog[i][j] = b.index(x[i][j]) + 1 # вот здесь проблема

for i in itog:
    print(*i)
```

Comment: Вы тестовую последовательность приведите, и что получить хотите. Хорошо бы еще указать часть кода, где подозреваете проблему. Так как я, например, ввел 4 и потом 1 2 3 4 и получил на выходе 4 1 и 3 2. То есть, как-то индексы перебираются, нет зависания. И вообще, хороший стиль - комментировать программу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменил код с учётом вашего первого уточнения ниже о том, что требуется. Так, как вы хотите, вообще вряд ли будет работать, как раз потому, что есть совпадения. Надо с самого начала "прикрепить"  к каждой карте её номер. Кроме того, после сортировки, чтобы карты попарно давали ровную сумму, можно просто после сортировки первую с последней давать - я вижу, что это вариация известной задачки, решение которой школьнику-Гауссу приписывают. Поэтому все циклы убрал, поставил простой вывод. Но потестируйте, если тесты не пройдут, то можете модифицировать свой цикл, просто работая с этим списком кортежей.
Просьба подтвердить, что это устраивает. И спросите, если что не ясно.

Кстати, не совсем понимаю, зачем с большей к меньшей выстраивать порядок, можно оставить и с меньшей к большей. Тем не менее, поставил `reverse=True`, раз у вас такая была идея.

```
n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
# "Прикрепляем" к каждой карте её номер
for i in range (len(a)):
    a[i]=(a[i],i+1)
# Сортируем
a.sort(reverse=True)
# Печатаем попарно индекс первого и последнего элемента
for i in range(n // 2):
    print (a[i][1], a[(-i-1)][1])
```

Comment: Не то, в вашем коде выводятся изначальные числа, которые распределяются из изначального списка между игроками. А надо вывести позиции этих чисел из изначального списка, что у меня и не получается. Так как не могу обойти то, что числа в изначальном списке могут повторяться, а индекс выводится первый при проходе списке.

Comment: @Tikhon, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если сильно понравилось:-)